# Designing a factory to create subclasses of a base class

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, factory-pattern, software-design

I'm designing a software that displays various charts, each using a well-defined, chart-dependent data. It seems a good idea to create a base class for the data and extend every chart-related data from it as they have a lot in common. It also seems reasonable to define an abstract base for the charts to handle drawing and some other functions. To reflect the chart-data relation in design, I'm using templates (code in Java):

```
public abstract class ChartData{
...
}

public abstract class Chart<T extends ChartData>{

  public abstract void onNewData(T data);

  ...

}

public class ConcreteData extends ChartData{
...
}

public class ConcreteChart<ConcreteData>{

  public void onNewData(ConcreteData data){
  ...
  }

...

}
```

This design works pretty well and is flexible enough for my needs. However, I'm receiving chart datas from various places (like database, network, etc.), and for testing purposes, I'm willing to create a data factory.

I'm trying to come up with an idea to make:

- a single class
- that is able to create all classes that extend ChartData
- that is flexible so it doesn't break my design

My best shot so far was creating an enumeration for the data types and adding a switch-case in a factory method, switching on a parameter. My problem is, having more than 10 classes that extend ChartData, this function's cyclomatic complexity is waaaaay above acceptable and breaks my 3rd rule.

The solution doesn't have to be a single method, but would be nice if it fit in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, I would probably avoid the switch cases by using reflection. The constraint would be that each ChartData class must have a parameterless constructor (or they must all have compatible constructors).

My Java's a bit rusty but I believe something like

```
public T createObject(Class<T> chartDataClass)
{
    chartDataClass.newInstance()
}
```

does it?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: Using reflection isn't quite what I'm looking for as I'd like a language-independent, architectural solution for the problem.